# i have problems with script. Help please

Tags: sql, sql-server, loops, recursion, common-table-expression

I write this post, i have this structure of table.

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMP 
(
 IdNode varchar(5), 
 IdSubNode varchar(5), 
 Lvl int 
)

INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES ('A', null,0), ('A','B',1), ('A','C',1), ('A','D',1)
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES ('B','B1',2), ('B','B2',2), ('B','B3',2)
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES ('D','D1',2), ('D','D2',2), ('D','D3',2)
INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES ('B1','BB1',3), ('B1','BB2',3), ('B1','BB3',3)

SELECT * FROM #TEMP
```

Please, i need a query like this:

```
/* -- I need this format
A / 
  / B /
      / B1 
           / BB1
           / BB2
           / BB3
      / B2 
      / B3
  / C /
  / D /
      / D1 
      / D2 
      / D3
*/
```

I will appreciate your help.

Comment: `i have problems with script. Help please` 
Please change your Subject line to be more descriptive and specific to your problem.

Comment: look up CONNECT BY or hierarchic queries, then try something, and when you are stuck again.. post a question.

Comment: Welcome to SO! From your question I can only guess that you want to print the result of the query in some tree-like, hierarchical format. If so, you should sepcify which programming language you use for your application, and you should tell us what you have tried so far. As it is right now, your question is too broad, not specific enough, and it is unlikely you will get help. You might want to read the "help" page (link in top right corner of this website) to understand how to best get help here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you want something like this?

```
SELECT DISTINCT *
FROM
(
SELECT DISTINCT IdNode AS '1st_Level'
FROM #TEMP
WHERE LEN(IdNode)=1
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT IdSubNode AS '1st_Level'
FROM #TEMP
WHERE LEN(IdSubNode) = 1)A

LEFT JOIN
(SELECT DISTINCT IdNode AS '2nd_Level'
FROM #TEMP
WHERE LEN(IdNode)=2
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT IdSubNode AS '2nd_Level'
FROM #TEMP
WHERE LEN(IdSubNode) = 2)B
ON A.[1st_Level] = LEFT(B.[2nd_Level],1)

LEFT JOIN
(SELECT DISTINCT IdNode AS '3rd_Level'
FROM #TEMP
WHERE LEN(IdNode)=3
UNION ALL
SELECT DISTINCT IdSubNode AS '3rd_Level'
FROM #TEMP
WHERE LEN(IdSubNode) = 3)C
ON LEFT(B.[2nd_Level],1) = LEFT(C.[3rd_Level],1)
```

Comment: thank you. I will try put the code in while. The lvl is dynamic.